# Illustrator alternative

Tags: software-recommendation

I have just migrated to Ubuntu a few months ago, and find myself wanting Illustrator again. What is the best alternative for vector based drawing? Can Gimp do vector as well, or is it mainly pixel based like Photoshop?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can try [Inkscape](http://packages.ubuntu.com/inkscape) [image: Install InkScape].

```
sudo apt install inkscape
```

[image]

It is built for vector graphics. If you need an animation tool, you can use [Synfig-studio](http://packages.ubuntu.com/synfig) [image: Install Synfig-studio].

```
sudo apt install synfig
```

GIMP can do vector graphics, but it is designed for (and **should** be used for) raster.

Comment: Can this open Illustrator files?

Comment: Yes it can. I've used .ai files in Inkscape before.

Answer (score 14):

There is also a helpful guide on using [Inkscape for Illustrator users](http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Inkscape_for_Adobe_Illustrator_users).

Answer (score 6):

*Inkscape* is a very, very good choice for that. It is built for vector graphics, which in many cases is exactly what you want.

For pixel graphics (photos, etc..) the *GIMP* is nicely powerful and fully-featured.

For Desktop publishing and Layouts, I like using *scribusNG*

Comment: Nice one, this will have me from having to ask sooner or later as i occasionally use desktop publisher as well.

Answer (score 5):

XaraExtreme http://www.xaraxtreme.org/

Answer (score 1):

OpenOffice.org Draw is another alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Inkscape is a good alternative, and if you want more complicated vector graphic, you could try [Torapp guilloche designer](http://www.torapp.info/en/s/guilloche.html), it is free and runs in Chrome 20 and above. No installation and plugin is needed.