# Is there any Adobe Illustrator-like software in Ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Illustrator alternative](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47347/illustrator-alternative)

Is there any graphic designing software for free in Ubuntu ?

Answer (score 3):

The two most popular in linux are [gimp](http://www.gimp.org/) and [inkscape](http://inkscape.org/) , both are in the ubuntu repositories. I hope they will fit your needs, but I know many people feel adobe makes great products and that the linux offerings do not measure up to what they are accustomed to.

Comment: GIMP is for Raster images, Inkscape is for vector images.