# What vector-image application can export in Corel or Adobe Illustrator formats?

Tags: adobe, inkscape, svg

Inkscape [seems to be the best alternative](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47347/illustrator-alternative) to Adobe Illustrator, but [as far as I can tell](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/FileFormat.html) it [can only read the AI SVG format](http://en.flossmanuals.net/inkscape/introduction/working-with-files/). There seems to be [a solution on Windows](http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Inkscape_for_Adobe_Illustrator_users#To_Save_Illustrator_Files_in_Inkscape_for_Windows) but I can't tell if that is also valid on Linux.

I need to provide some vector art to a vendor in either **Corel** or **Adobe Illustrator** formats.

**What Linux applications can I use?**

The vector art is quite simple, so it's not a problem if I have to re-create it in a new application. What counts is that the output file is a format recognized by the industry.

Comment: Surely SVG is an industry standard? I think you will have to use Corel or Adobe if you want to be sure of your file being totally compatible.

Comment: Actually, Inkscape **can** open/import Corel Draw (.cdr) and Adobe Illustrator (.ai) files, as well as save to [those formats](http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Frequently_asked_questions#What_formats_can_Inkscape_import.2Fexport.3F) (I'm not 100% sure it can save as '.cdr', though.. 'ai' is fine, though). To support the Corel Draw format, you need to install `python-uniconvertor` from your package manager.

Comment: @edmj000: Yes. I was careful not to say _industry standard_ because you're right but my engraver doesn't care about standards :-) He only cares that he can open the files with the "de-facto standard" applications he's got.

Comment: @SirCharlo: Great! My understanding was that AI was not supported out of the box. I will have to just try it out and see if my engraver's output matches my expectations then!

Comment: Yeah give it a shot! The FAQ states that "Inkscape natively supports opening or importing SVG, SVGZ (gzipped SVG), PDF, and AI (Adobe Illustrator) formats", so you should be ok! :)

Comment: @SirCharlo No, Inkscape doesn't save either CDR or AI. No free software does.

Comment: Inkscape's FAQ: "Inkscape can save as SVG, SVGZ, PDF, Postscript/EPS/EPSi, **Adobe Illustrator (*.ai)**, LaTeX (*.tex), POVRay (*.pov), HPGL, and others"

Comment: @SirCharlo That FAQ is wrong and you are arguing against a developer of the application in question ;) Please use your own experience. Blindly quoting something isn't very helpful. We'll fix the FAQ, of course.

Comment: Sorry! No harm intended :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Corel as well as Illustrator can recognize and read SVG format. But the problem is that sometimes they don't open SVG properly.
Generally some publishers can print from pdf. I think, the main issue is to get along with the publishing house about the file prepared for print.

Answer (score 1):

You can Use [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/) you can import the ilustrator 9.0 version file, and corel 7 X14 version files but i don't recommend to you those formats because the conversion is not so good.
Normally wen i have to deal with files from others programs, i use PDF or SVG the standart file of Inkscape.

I hope i have helped.

http://inkscape.org/

Comment: I was asking about export ("save as") - not about importing from Corel or Illustrator.

Comment: ok in that case you can save us in inkscape to export to *.Ai, *.Cdr, *.eps, *.ps but some filters of the inskcape don't be exported like shadows or blurs you can export like PDF, either corel or Ilustrator can import PDF flawlessly(the blurs or other filters are imported in raster).

Comment: Look, Inkscape **doesn't** save CDR or AI :)

Comment: mine saves :D 
You are using on Linux or windows ?
in windows you have to install postscript tools..

Comment: Inkscape's FAQ: "Inkscape can save as SVG, SVGZ, PDF, Postscript/EPS/EPSi, **Adobe Illustrator (.ai)**, LaTeX (.tex), POVRay (*.pov), HPGL, and others"

Comment: ups ... you have right ... but you can try out the EPS.. is the system i use for photoshop compatibility. I forgot to say that the color that inkscape exports is RGB.. if that matters..

Comment: @Ricaxe Yes, EPS or PDF might do the job. Both exporters have issues, but that's something already. Still, I would send SVG too; just save it as plain SVG, because Ai and CDR don't read sodipodi/inkscape superset of SVG features.

Comment: try Postscript ps... i think if is only vector art you should have no problem, the color if important, you have to be careful.